# Why am i getting totally different from normal print out using PDFBox?

Tags: java, apache, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I have an issue to print PDF file using PDFBox. Its totally different from normal print out. 
I implement a java program to print a PDF.

```
PDFPageable pdfPageable =new PDFPrinter(document).getPageable();
printerJob.setPageable(pdfPageable);
printerJob.print(printRequestAttributeSet);
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting totally different from normal print out?

Comment: Please provide a PDF which illustrates the issue.

Comment: And also the printout. Either scan it, or print it to  virtual PDF printer so that we will find out what "totally different from normal print out" means - do you have a pink background, is it rotated 45°, are there glyphs missing, or is it mirrored, or does it contain new text? Read also the questions about PDFBox printing from the last few days.

Comment: when  i print the pdf file right click and send to printer and java + pdfbox its different. such as text, layout and ect

Comment: yeah, but HOW it is different? We can only solve this by getting the PDF and the rendered image. You can render the image in a file by using the "PDFReader" option of the command line application. And see also my other comment in the answer re: problems with the very last version. Maybe open an issue with JIRA and attach your PDF and the rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

Seams your using the PDFBox jar snapshot. I have seen they are giving frequent release. I think you better communicated with the Dev support team and get it done. Seams is a rendering issue.

Comment: you are correct I'm using the latest pdfbox snapshot for my development.

Comment: I just realize - the last change (rev 1595992) has a problem, see my comment at the end of PDFBOX-1689. The best is that you go back to the previous one or wait until it is fixed (hopefully tonight).

Comment: Guys.. even i set the document to printable printerJob.setPrintable(
      new PDFPrinter(document).getPageable().getPrintable(
        document.getNumberOfPages() - 1),
      new PDFPrinter(document).getPageable().getPageFormat(
        document.getNumberOfPages() - 1)); now i face some font issue.

Comment: Well yes, the change mentioned at the end of PDFBOX-1689 does have a font issue. Why don't you get a version from a few days ago?

Comment: Could you please tell me which version dosnt have the font issue. I'm talking about 2.0.0 snapshots

Comment: Try the earlierst one that you can find in the snapshot directory, i.e. from May 20. If your file isn't confidential, please attach it to PDFBOX-1689.

Comment: The PDFBox snapshots are now up to date again. The last from May 26 should be stable. If you have still problems with fonts, please file an issue with JIRA.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (adapted from the example in the [java api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html))

```
  import java.io.*;
  import javax.print.*;
  import javax.print.attribute.*; 
  import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;  

 public class PrintTest{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    FileInputStream psStream = null;
    try {
        psStream = new FileInputStream("some.pdf");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
          ffne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (psStream == null) {
            return;
        }
    DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);  
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);

    // this step is necessary because I have several printers configured
    PrintService myPrinter = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++){
        System.out.println("service found: "+svcName);
        String svcName = services[i].toString();           
        if (svcName.contains("printer closest to me")){
            myPrinter = services[i];
            System.out.println("my printer found: "+svcName);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (myPrinter != null) {            
        DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
        try {
        job.print(myDoc, aset);

        } catch (Exception pe) {pe.printStackTrace();}
    } else {
        System.out.println("no printer services found");
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: well, this answer is based on javax api. My question is about PDFBox. Also i have issue with print out. what i get is totally differences from normal print out